# How to add a day with a specific date using add_months function

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I am trying to add a day with a specific date using **add_months** in oracle database.
I wrote this line:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS('01-JAN-2018', MONTHS_BETWEEN('02-JAN-2018', '01-JAN-2018')) FROM DUAL;
```

this returns:

```
01-JAN-18
```

Why doesn't it return **02-JAN-18**?? Can I add one day to the date using this function?

Comment: please check your tags put the tags according to your database if you are using oracle don't put SQL tag

Comment: From your comment "I want to add 1 day to the date", just use +1 , for example:  select sysdate + 1 from dual;

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to add one day, using a function that is specifically named "add **months**"? Use simple date arithmetic - add 1 to a date to add one day, or add `interval '1' day`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't it return 02-JAN-18??

According to [**MONTHS_BETWEEN**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2028.htm#OLADM604) documentation,

> The MONTHS_BETWEEN function calculates the number of months between
>   two dates. When the two dates have the same day component or are both
>   the last day of the month, then the return value is a whole number.
>   Otherwise, the return value includes a **fraction that considers the
>   difference in the days based on a 31-day month**

So,

```
select MONTHS_BETWEEN('02-JAN-2018', '01-JAN-2018') FROM DUAL ;
```

yields

```
.0322580645161290322580645161290322580645
```

`ADD_MONTHS`  returns the date date plus integer months.
So, `.0322..` is considered as integer 0 and your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS('01-JAN-2018', 0) FROM DUAL;
```

In order to add 1 months, simply take the difference of two dates.

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-02' - DATE '2018-01-01') FROM DUAL;
```

Or better, add an `INTERVAL`  of 1 month

```
SELECT DATE '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH FROM DUAL;
```

To answer your question, **add 1 day**, simply use

```
SELECT DATE '2018-01-01' + 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I want to add 1 day to the date. Please edit the answer so that i can make it accepted answer.

Comment: @Imad062 : Check now.

Comment: Just an information, `+ INTERVAL '1' MONTH` is not the same as `ADD_MONTHS(..., 1)`. For `ADD_MONTHS` you have: *If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month.* For `+ INTERVAL '1' MONTH` you would get an `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`